# Remove list of elements before iterating in java

Tags: java, collections

I have a String List.On a satisfied Condition ,I need to group strings and remove those before iterating.
For example;

```
List<String> test = new ArrayList();
List<String> newLst = new ArrayList();
test.add("A1");
test.add("A2");
test.add("A3");
test.add("A1B1");
test.add("C1");
for(String s: test){
    if(s.startsWith("A"){
        newLst.add(s);
        test.remove(s);
    }
}
```

Once A1 reaches the loop,collect related string in new list and remove it from existing.

Getting Concurrent Modification exception.Kindly help to solve this.

Output:
newLst: A1,A2,A3 
test : A1B1,C1

newLst : A1B1
test:C1

newLst : C1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterating through a Collection, avoiding ConcurrentModificationException when removing objects in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/iterating-through-a-collection-avoiding-concurrentmodificationexception-when-re)

Comment: `test.removeIf(s -> s.startsWith("A") && newLst.add(s));`

Answer (score 1):

You could use an explicit `Iterator` to iterate over the `List`, and use that `Iterator`'s `remove()` method inside the loop (instead of `List`'s `remove()`), but it would be simpler to remove from `test` all the elements added to `newLst` after the loop:

```
for(String s: test){
    if(s.startsWith("A"){
        newLst.add(s);
    }
}
test.removeAll(newLst);
```

Comment: Using an `Iterator` to remove the matches yields quadratic time complexity due to the linear complexity of `ArrayList`’s remove operation. Using `removeAll` avoids that for the removal but brings in a similar time complexity due to the hidden dependency to `contains` on `newList`. A short solution avoiding both, is `test.removeIf(s -> s.startsWith("A") && newLst.add(s));`.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter out elements starting with A using stream:

```java
List<String> result = test.stream()
            .filter(line -> line.startsWith("A")) 
            .collect(Collectors.toList()); 
result.forEach(System.out::println);  //This is for printing elements
```

Answer (score 1):

**Why you are getting `ConcurrentModificationException` ?**

That's because you are trying to modify the collection while iterating over it's items. The only safe way to modify your collection during iteration  `Iterator.remove()`; The same applies for `Iterator.add()` (Whether you delete or add an item it counts as a modification).

**JDK < 8 SOLUTION**

```
List<String> sourceList = new ArrayList();
List<String> destList = new ArrayList();
sourceList.add("A1");
sourceList.add("A2");
sourceList.add("A3");
sourceList.add("A1B1");
sourceList.add("C1");
Iterator<String> iterator = sourceList.iterator();

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    String s = iterator.next();
    if(s.startsWith("A"){
        destList.add(s);
        iterator.remove(s);
    }
}
```

**JDK > 8 SOLUTION**

```
List<String> destList = sourceList.stream()
      .filter(item -> item.startsWith("A")) 
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note that Java `streams` use `Spliterator` which quite different than an `Iterator`.

> A stream source is described by an abstraction called Spliterator. As its name suggests, Spliterator combines two behaviors: accessing the elements of the source (iterating), and possibly decomposing the input source for parallel execution (splitting).

For further details , i advise you to check this interesting post about [how streams works under the hood](https://developer.ibm.com/articles/j-java-streams-3-brian-goetz/)